# How can i get to match the pattern as follows

Tags: php, regex

I need to match the pattern

```
<a class="item-link" href="NEED TO GET THIS PART">AND THIS PART</a>
```

I tried all three regex patterns but none seem to help me.

```
preg_match_all("/<a.*(?:[^class=\"item-link\"=]*)class=\"item-link\"(?:[^href=]*)href=(?:'|\")?(.*)(?:'|\")(?:[^>]*)>(.*)<\/a>/", $content, $tablecontent);
preg_match_all("|/<a (?:[^href=]*)href=(?:'|\")?(.*)(?:'|\")(?:[^>]*)>(.*)<\/a>/|s", $content, $tablecontent); 
preg_match_all("|/<a.+class=\"item-link\".+href=\"(.*)\"[^>]*>\.+<\/a[^>]*>/|m", $content, $tablecontent);
print_r($tablecontent);
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions, use a HTML parser.

Comment: What's the context of the problem? If you want to parse HTML, then use an HTML parser.

Comment: HTML parser... im not familiar with it.. i tried to write the above code but can find it to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/<a class="item-link" href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>/', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'a' in

Comment: I fixed that... sorry. I forgot to add a \ in front the of the / in </a>.

Comment: Are you there that what you're trying to match is exactly in the format you specified about? If there are more spaces or additional attributes, that the regular expression I gave you won't work. What variable are you outputting?  The matches will be in $matches. I tried it and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to do this:

```
$html = '<a class="item-link" href="NEED TO GET THIS PART">AND THIS PART</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new XPath($dom);

$results = $xp->query('//a[class="item-link"]');

foreach ($results as $link) {
   $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
   $text = $link->nodeValue;

   ... do your stuff here ...
}
```

Overkill for a single link, but by far the easiest way when dealing with a full HTML page.